# "This is a startup partition. You can't erase it" On Disk Utility

Tags: mac, disk-utility, partition

[image]

I want to expand my Windows partition. I saw all the tutorials on youtube and they said to drag the drive on the corner. However, the Disk partitions doesn't have a drive for me to drag and said that it was a startup partition so I can't decrease it's size.

Comment: I'm assuming Windows is already installed on the partition?

Comment: Your 1st partition named "Macintosh HD" seems to be full. Please verify this key point.

Comment: @danielAzuelos, how do you get that from his post?

Comment: The warning `Disk Utility` gave you is an answer to an attempt to erase your actual "startup partition".

Comment: → Flying: from the high water mark on *her* "Macintosh HD" partition.

Comment: If you are referring to the blue area around "Macintosh HD", isn't it just showing THAT is the selected partition, and showing it's info to the right?

Comment: @danielAzuelos, my bad, you are correct.  The blue is the used space on the volume.

Comment: The blue outline shows it is selected - the blue fill, however, shows it's full to the brim ;) So it won't do it for 2 reasons, boot drive & full.

Comment: I deleted some files and have 20+GB in my Mac disk, i still can't move the partition . :/

Answer (score 1):

In order to increase your Windows partition, you will need to first free up disk space on your Macintosh HD partition, as it appears to be full.  128GB isn't very much these days, I would recommend getting a larger hard drive, but transferring larger, less frequently used items such as movies or videos can often help free up large amount of space.